Is “〜てきた” with state-change verbs ambiguous or not?
I read incredibly conflicting information about this. What I mean is say “なってきた”, what I read is:

It means “It has become”, but implies a more gradual process than “なった” on it's own does.
It means “It started to become.” or “It is becoming.”, implying the change started in the past and is currently ongoing, and not completed.
It can mean either, depending on context.

The reason I ask is because I had the opinion that it could be either, but with a bias towards the the second interpretation, but then someone told me it can only be the second interpretation and always implies the process has not yet completed and is still ungoing so I took that to heart but now I read “少しだけ慣れてきた。”, for whatever reason, in that context, I interpreted it as “I have gotten used to it a little.”, not necessarily implying that the speaker would get used to it more in the future and the process is continuing so I decided to look this particular usage up on weblio and virtually all of the translations there imply the process is finalized and non-continuing, such as:

彼はクラスに慣れてきたようで、私たちはほっとしている。


We're relieved that he seems to have gotten used to class.

Now. I am mindful of that “getting used to” is something one can argue of that one can always get more used to it, and that thus “I have gotten used to it.” may imply the process is still continuing as well. But the way I read that line when I encountered it, as well as many of the translations on Weblio, is that the speaker does not currently feel the process is continuing on. But for instance in if I were to see “もう暗くなってきた。” I would interpret it as “It's getting dark already.” or “It's started to get dark already.” as in the process is not finished yet and currently underway and it will only get darker from now.
So what's going on with this usage of “〜てきた”? Does it by necessity imply that the process will continue from here and the result will intensify in greater magnitude. Or can it also be used when the transformation has reached it's ultimate state already and will not continue any further or does it heavily rely on the verb in some way? For whatever reason my mind wants to read “慣れてきた。” as completed. Maybe that has something to do with the fact that unlike “なっている”, “慣れている” essentially always means “is used to” never “is getting used to”, which would in fact be “慣れてきている"? I'm not sure how right my mind is about this though. Like, say that “慣れてきた。” does mean the process has finalized. Does this apply to any such verb such as say “結婚してきた” or “死んできた”?

Contrary to your expectation, クラスに慣れてきた, 暗くなってきた and so on mean the process is not yet complete, so "started to ～" may be more accurate. 少し慣れてきた means the process has just started, whereas 完全に慣れてきた means the process is nearly complete (but not 100% complete). Still, "It has become dark" and similar expressions are natural enough translations in many cases, so I don't think you always have to use "started/starting" to translate this.
On the other hand, この職場で10年働いてきた and such say nothing about whether this state will continue to be true in the future. The person who said this may quit today, or continue to work for another 10 years. In English, the present perfect aspect ("I've worked here for 10 years") happens to work for both cases. (Note that the present perfect in English is also versatile and can express several different things, which is often a source of headache for learners.)
結婚する and 死ぬ are typical "instant state-change only" verbs, and they don't work well with -てくる/-てきた (at least for the purpose of indicating aspect). We always say 結婚して10年になった instead of 10年間結婚してきた.
